# Polyline disappears randomly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-polyline

I built an application using the Google API, this application receives the coordinates from specific locations, and draws the flight through a polyline.

One of the requirements for this project is to use a polyline with a stroke, so I had to do a trick, I added two polylines, one for the border and the other one for the polyline inner.

When I receive a new coordinate from the server I call this function to push into the flight path array:

```
/**
 * Save received coordinates from web socket
 * @param {float} lat1 Latitude from the current address
 * @param {float} lon1 Longitude from the current address
 */
saveCoordinates: function (lat1, lon1) {
    var polylineData = {
        lat: lat1,
        lng: lon1
    };
    ES.util.Helper.GlobalVars.flightPathCoordinates.push(polylineData);
}
```

And I'm calling this function to draw the polylines:

```
   /**
     * Draw Polyline
     * @param {gmap} map Google Maps Widget
     */
    initPolylineDraw: function(map) {

        var polylineBorder = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: ES.util.Helper.GlobalVars.flightPathCoordinates,
            strokeColor: '#fc302e', 
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 7,
            optimized: false
        });

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: ES.util.Helper.GlobalVars.flightPathCoordinates,
            strokeColor: '#d6adac',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 4,
            optimized: false
        });

        ES.util.Helper.Polyline.drawPoints(polyline, map);

        polylineBorder.setMap(map);
        polyline.setMap(map);

    }
```

But there is something wrong with my code, because sometimes one of the polylines disappears. Like on this example:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm0FU.png)

I opened two pages, connected at the same server, and received the same coordinates, and the page on the left side redraw the polyline without the stroke randomly, but this bug didn't happened at the page on the right side.

This bug only appears sometimes, which is really weird and hard to know the cause.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: redraw both polylines, making sure the smaller one is on top.

Comment: the smaller one is on the top when the application starts, I can confirm this because I'm setting the map on the bigger polyline first

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.